# Control UTC time in server side Dynamicscrm

Tags: dynamics-crm, utc

I saved a record in 17:16:15,  I run a job which gets the ModifiedOn field of my record and I got- 15:16:15, my GMT is +2, I want to know how to fix that gap that my result will turn out like it should be - 17:16:15. I can't select it from DB I need a solution in server side (c# I mean)  what can U do in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DateTimes are always saved in UTC in the database. *

You need to dynamically convert from UTC into your local time zone. In C#, you can do this with the `.ToLocalTime()` method as long as your code is running in the correct time zone. You can also find your local time in the `FormattedValues` collection of the response, which uses your Dynamics timezone user settings . But the raw datetime value in the database will always be in UTC.

* The only exception to this is if the DateTime field is set to “TimeZone Independent” in the attribute type settings. But be careful: once you set this option you can’t change it for that field again.